# Understanding surface integrals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

My question is a bit vague, but I'm trying to get a better understanding of surface integrals and their relation to physics. Suppose I have a surface, say a sphere, and I have a function which gives the temperature of the sphere at any point. My textbook says that if I want to find the average temperature of a point on the surface of the sphere, I integrate this temperature function over the entire surface and divide by the surface area. I can understand this intuitively - the integral is like the infinitesimal sum of area times temperature, so dividing through by area gives the average temperature. What I don't understand is what physical quantity the value of the integral (before division) represents? I know it will have units temperature*m^2 but that's it.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: If you do it discretely, do you still have conceptual problems? If I have three glasses of water at different temperatures $x, y$ and $z$, and I asked you to tell me the average temperature, would you wonder what $x+y+z$ represented before you divided it by $3$? That's the same physical quantity as your surface integral, so if you're wondering about one and not the other, then your problems are possibly closer to not really understanding surface integrals as a mathematical concept.

Comment: Ah ok, that comparison really helped, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since thermal energy $E = c T$ is proportional to temperature (in Kelvin), then the integral will represent (up to a multiplicative constant) the total thermal energy of the sphere. The constant is not non-dimensional, though, and depends on the properties of the material.